# Why will the string from req.session.token not be equal to the string from req.headers?

Tags: javascript, string, redis, session-storage

I am working on a node/express project and I have stored the token generated during login to req.session. I have a middleware that checks if the token coming from the request headers is same as that stored in the req.session but everything I have tried returned false. I have confirmed that both of them are same strings and of equal length.

Expected

> req.session.token === token(from request headers); //true

Actual

> req.session.token === token(from request headers); //false

I have tried to JSON.stringify both strings, trim and used regex but everything returned false. What could be wrong and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching and debugging, I discovered this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-JavaScript). I eventually resolved it by checking

> ```
> >  if (string1.localeCompare(string2) === 0) {
> >           //if the result returns 0 then both strings are equal
> >          // do something }
> ```